# The app won't let me close questions on a beta site where I'm under 3k rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, android-app, beta-sites

On beta sites, the privilege to close questions requires only 500 reputation. On other sites, this privilege requires 3000 reputation.

On Board & Card Games, [I have over 500 rep](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/5573/) and can close questions - if I'm using the website.

On the Android App, however, this doesn't show up in the question options. It's usually the last item on the list.

[image: wanted: one close button. reward: my gratitude.]

I'm using Android App 1.0.26 on a HTC One running Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well that was a fun one.

The API was screwing up loading privilege reputation level *overrides*, which for historical reasons is how most of the different privilege levels in betas work.

There was another, unrelated it turned out, issue with caching the `can_*` fields that control that bit of UI.  It was possible, if you requested exactly the right set of fields, for the API to serve a request for `can_*` out of a previously cached response.  I don't think that happened in your case, but it was discovered while investigating your problem.

Fixes for both went out in the most recent API deploy.  You don't need to update your app or anything, it should just work now.